# Request originated from VNET through service endpoint. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-virtual-network

I am working on a closing all of my resources in a private network in Azure, for the time being I have select 3 resources. 1. Function App 2. Azure Cosmos DB 3. Azure Storage Account

I have created an function app with following network settings

[image]

I have selected inbound access as open for now. And in outbound access, I have enabled VNET integration with a subnet named app-subnet.

I have created a cosmos DB account for MongoDB API with private end point enabled in same VNET but in different subnet named az-subnet.

Same process I have done for storage account.(using az-subnet)

Now I am able to access storage account from function app, but not cosmos DB.

Error on saving document is

```
Request originated from VNET through service endpoint. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings
```

Please help, like exactly what I am missing here.

Comment: In your `Firewall and virtual networks` blade is the option set to `selected networks only` without any exceptions? Did you create the DNS records or use the `Integrate with private DNS zone` when creating the private link? Is there an A record in your DNS zone that redirects from your cosmos name to the private IP address?

Comment: @404 yes, I have choose ````Integrate with private DNS zone````  at the time of creating private endpoint and also I have verified it has created an A record in DNS zone

Comment: Then I'm not sure. Maybe a custom DNS on your vnet or NSG's blocking traffic on some ports? You could try placing a small linux VM in the subnet and test if an `nslookup <YourCosmosName>.documents.azure.com` returns the private IP address so you are sure at least that part of the solution is working.

Comment: And is the private DNS zone linked to the vnet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Configure the service endpoint for the Azure virtual network and subnet. You can do it in Cosmos DB settings' `Firewall and virtual networks` option.

Follow below steps:

1. Select **Firewalls and virtual networks** from the settings menu, and choose to allow access from **Selected networks**.
2. To grant access to an existing virtual network's subnet, under Virtual networks, select Add existing Azure virtual network.
3. Select the **Subscription** from which you want to add an Azure virtual network. Select the Azure **Virtual networks** and **Subnets** that you want to provide access to your Azure Cosmos DB account. Next, select **Enable** to enable selected networks with service endpoints for "Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB". When it's complete, select **Add**. Refer below image.

[image]

4. After the Azure Cosmos DB account is enabled for access from a virtual network, it will allow traffic from only this chosen subnet. The virtual network and subnet that you added should appear as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

**Note:** Configuring a VNET service endpoint may take up to 15 minutes to propagate and the endpoint may exhibit an inconsistent behavior during this period.

Source: [Configure access to Azure Cosmos DB from virtual networks (VNet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-vnet-service-endpoint)

Comment: This defeats the whole point of setting up a private link endpoint.

Comment: sorry but I didn't get you. You need to add app-subnet (in which azure function deployed) in cosmos DB firewall settings to access it from Azure function. Your connection is secure and not allowed but other not allowed networks.

Comment: Service endpoints versus a privatelink endpoint are two different solutions that should both work. If you setup a privatelink endpoint you want to block any access from the public endpoint and use the prive endpoint instead. Private link goes a step further into isolating your resources as you are able to restrict to the single cosmosDB instead of any cosmosDB (like service endpoints would), which e.g. would also prevent any data exfiltration to other databases.

Comment: But if I did so, there is no benefit of deploying private endpoint for cosmos DB ??

Comment: @404 do you have any idea/suggestion on what I am missing in this ?