# Trying to access CosmosDB with private endpoint causes 'request originated from VNET through service endpoint' error?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I have a Node Js app which interacts with CosmosDB and which is deployed to a private AKS cluster. I was able to connect to Cosmos DB through a service endpoint in the Cluster VNET/subnet for Cosmos DB by enabling 'selected networks' in Cosmos DB.

I am now trying to close it to private access only via private endpoints.

I disabled public access / so no 'selected networks' any more.

I created a private endpoint and private link to Cosmos DB and integrated it with a Private DNS Zone that is in the same resource group as the Cluster VNET and uses one of the VNET subnets.

When I do nslookup in the cluster from a test pod I can see that the `cosmosname.documents.azure.com` URI has canonical name = `cosmosname.privatelink.documents.azure.com`. The address however is a different IP address than the ones in the DNS zone records.

When I try to run the app, I get the error:

```bash
Request originated from VNET through service endpoint. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [sf], as it's infrastructure and not programming

Comment: It's a very similar question to this one which never had a suitable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639169/request-originated-from-vnet-through-service-endpoint-this-is-blocked-by-your-c 

But I have also now made a second post on Server Fault.

Comment: Did you link the private DNS zone to your vnet?

Comment: @NotFound Yes, I created a link between the Private DNS Zone and the Cluster VNET and Subnet.

Comment: And the exact name of the private DNS zone is `privatelink.documents.azure.com` with the record being named `cosmosname` (I assume a placeholder, but your cosmos db name).

Comment: Yes that's the name of the private DNS zone @NotFound

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem because there was a separate DNS Zone subscription that records needed to be created in. There was a policy preventing the DNS Zones in the Cluster subscription from being used.